Quantifying prediction uncertainty using deep ensembles: How to combine Laplace distributions?
For a regression problem, I want to train an ensemble of deep neural networks to predict the labeled output as well as the uncertainty, similar to the approach presented in the paper Simple and Scalable Predictive Uncertainty Estimation using Deep Ensembles. The authors use the negative log-likelihood (NLL) of the Gaussian distribution as loss function to make the model implicitly learn the variance
$$
{\ell_\text{NLL}}_G =
-\log p_G\left(y \mid \hat \mu, \hat\sigma^2\right)=
\frac{\log \hat\sigma^2}{2}+
\frac{\left(y-\hat \mu\right)^2}
{2 \hat\sigma^2}+
\text{constant}
$$
where $y$ is the target, $\hat \mu$ is the predicted mean, and $\hat \sigma^2$ is the predicted variance.
However, I noticed my models are converging better when using the mean average error instead of the mean square error as loss function. Therefore I want to make use of the Laplacian NLL, which should be more robust to outliers:
$$
{\ell_\text{NLL}}_L =
-\log p_L\left(y \mid \hat \mu, \hat b\right)=
\log \hat b +
\frac{\left|y-\hat \mu\right|}{\hat b} + 
\text{constant}
$$
where $\hat b$ is the predicted scale parameter.
In the Gaussian case the authors then combine the the predicted means and variances of the individual models $m$:
$$
\mu_*=\frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M \hat \mu_m \\
\text{Var}(\mu_*) = \sigma_*^2=\frac{1}{M} \left(\sum_{m=1}^M\hat\sigma_m^2+\hat \mu_m^2\right)-\mu_*^2
$$
What is the correct approach to calculate the means and variances for mixed Laplace distributions?

What do you mean by "converging better?"

In my observations, using the MAE loss instead of the MSE loss consistently resulted in lower train and validation RMSEs (as well as other metrics, like the Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency coefficient, which is commonly used in my field). I am unsure why this is the case, but I imagined the MAE loss encourages the optimizer to find a lower local minimum.

Interesting... in any case, means add, and so do variances, regardless of the underlying distribution.  So, the calculations will be the same for the mixture of Laplaces as they will be for the mixture of Gaussians.

jbowman pointed out that the rules about the mixture of means and variances apply to Laplacian as they do to Gaussian distributions. The averaged estimates $\mu_*$ and variance estimates $\text{Var}(\mu_*)$ can be calculated from the $M$ ensemble members like so:
$$
\mu_*=\frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M \hat \mu_m \\
\text{Var}(\mu_*) = 2 b_*^2=\frac{1}{M} \left(\sum_{m=1}^M2 \hat b_m^2+\hat \mu_m^2\right)-\mu_*^2
$$
